# What's the difference between R and R.drawable?

Tags: java, android, r.java-file

`R` and `R.drawable` are two different classes within the Android framework, both of which inherit from `Object`. They seem very similar to me; what's different about them?

Comment: This question is discussed [on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307091/when-are-difference-between-questions-considered-opinion-based-and-when-not?cb=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android.R is a set of built in constants provided by the android SDK. The R class represents the resources in the Android.R xml file.

The R.drawable class contains resources which can be drawn on to the screen. E.g. Bitmaps, NinePatchDrawble etc...